# Enzyme TypeError: _reactDom2.default.render is not a function

Tags: reactjs, enzyme

I have search all stackoverflow and github issues and haven't found a solution for this. I currently have a project that uses `react@15.4.1` and I am trying to set up `Enzyme`.

Whenever I try to `Enzyme.mount()` a component I get the following error:

`TypeError: _reactDom2.default.render is not a function`

However if I `Enzyme.shallow()` shallow render the component it works.

Here is a sample test that shows the code that triggers the error:

**TestComponent.test.js**

```
import { configure, mount, shallow } from "enzyme"
import Adapter from "enzyme-adapter-react-15.4"

import React from "react"
import TestComponent from "./TestComponent"

configure({ adapter: new Adapter() })

describe("Example Tests", () => {
  test("mount does not work", () => {

    const shallowRendered = shallow(<TestComponent />) <-- this works
    const mountedComponent = mount(<TestComponent />) <-- this throws

  })
})
```

**TestComponent.js**

```
import React from "react"

export default class TestComponent extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <p>test</p>
  }
}
```

**package.json**

```
//...
"dependencies": {
   //...
   "react": "15.4.1",
   "react-dom: "15.4.1"
}
"devDependencies": {
   //...
   "babel-jest": "24.1.0",
   "enzyme": "~3.3.0",
   "react-addons-test-utils": "15.4.1",
   "react-test-renderer": "15.4.1",
   "enzyme-adapter-react-15.4": "^1.3.1"
}
```

**jest.config.js**

```
module.exports = {
  verbose: true,
  collectCoverageFrom: ["<rootDir>/src/client/**/*.{js,jsx}"],
  testPathIgnorePatterns: [
    "node_modules",
    "build",
  ],
  transform: {
    "^.+\\.js$": "babel-jest",
  },
  testEnvironment: "jsdom",
  transformIgnorePatterns: ["<rootDir>/node_modules/"],
  moduleNameMapper: {
    "\\.(css|less)$": "<rootDir>/src/client/__mocks__/styleMock.js",
  },
  testURL: "http://localhost",
}
```

Comment: I got the same issue (`shallow` works but `mount` and `render`). It seems no one ever encountered this, or haven't found a solution...

Answer (score 1):

You need to import { configure } from enzyme.

```js
import { configure } from 'enzyme'
import Adapter from 'enzyme-adapter-react-16'

configure({ adapter: new Adapter()  })
```